# Create a table before loading fixtures into rails test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

One of the table's db schema specifies its partitioned on a column.
Since fixtures are loaded before a test starts, the INSERT statements fails since partition table doesn't exist.
I tried to

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  self.use_transactional_tests = false
  fixtures :fixture_file
  setup :setup

  def setup
     ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE TABLE table_1 PARTITION OF table ..")
  end
```

This seems to fail since fixtures are getting loaded before setup is invoked.
Is there a way to invoke setup before loading fixtures?

Comment: so you want your test db structure is different from your development/production db structure ?

Comment: @Lam Pham No, my question is, how to run a setup method that creates partition tables and then execute load fixtures for test db?
Right now, despite having a setup method in the test class, fixtures are getting loaded before creating partition tables.

Comment: sorry but iam still not get your point, why do you need to create `partition tables` ? do you concern about the performance (on test ?) or something else ?

Comment: @LamPhan when I ran some tests, fixtures were not getting inserted because the table was throwing a "no partition of relation found for row" error.
So I had to create the partition tables during setup and then load the fixtures to get past the error.
During teardown, i simply drop the tables.
What do you think of this approach?

Answer (score 1):

I was not aware that fixtures can be selectively loaded into a test class.
test_helper.rb

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :A, :B
end
```

whereas in the test class where I want to create a partition table first followed by loading fixtures, I tried

```
class ApiTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_1 PARTITION OF table FOR VALUES IN (1)")
    ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.create_fixtures(Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures'), 'table_fixture_file')
  end

  def teardown
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_1")
  end

end
```